# geo_field in validation is read as str

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gis, django-rest-framework-gis

I'm trying to migrate a project from django-rest-framework-gis  0.7 to 0.8 and from django-rest-framework 2.4.3. to 3.0.5. I solved a lot of errors but I've stoped on the following problem.

My GeoFeatureModelSerializer has these properties:

```
class Meta:
     model = RoadRoute
     id_field = False
     geo_field = 'geom'
     fields = ('auth_code', 'states', 'creation_date')


def validate(self, attrs):
     if len(attrs['states']) > 0:
          states = State.objects.filter(code__in=attrs['states']).unionagg()
          if attrs['geom'].within(states) is False:
               raise ValidationError(_('Route is not within the allowed states.'))
          else:
               return attrs
     else:
          raise ValidationError(_('States field can not be empty.'))
```

On my tests, I'm having that error:

```
File "/home/wille/py-projects/routes_registry_api/routes_registry_api/routes/serializers.py", line 59, in validate
    if attrs['geom'].within(states) is False:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'within'
```

The geom field is not being read as a GeometryField, but as a str. In the 0.7 version of DRF-gis that same code worked correctly.